Shortcut in vs code to create multiple li with h2 inside
I know typing li*4 i create 4 li
 but i want to achieve this: 
                        <li><h2></h2></li>
                        <li><h2></h2></li>
                        <li><h2></h2></li>

What i need to type to write this?
Something like li{h2*4}*4 but it doesnt works

li*3>span seems to be the format.  But the trouble is that h2 is a block-level element that doesn't behave like a span (inline element).  So li*3>h2 doesn't work.

You can do (li>h2)*4. (uses grouping).
li*4>h2 also works.

@SergeyChikuyonok Do these suggestions produce the h2's inline as the question wants?   The h2's are always indented on their own line for me.
